# How to prepopulate a cascaded drop down and attachment on validation failure

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 drop downs, just for simplicity let's say they are Country / States.

```
<select id="country_id" name = "country_id">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $country->id; ?>" <?php if (null !== set_value("country_id") && set_value("country_id") == $country->id) : echo ' selected '; ?>>$country->name;
  <?php endforeach?>
</select>

<select id="state_id" name = "state_id">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>

<input type="file" name="attachment_id" value="" />
```

What I do is when the country is selected I populate the states. This I do using AJAX and ".change" and this works well

The problem I'm having is when I do form_validation and

```
$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE
```

Then I reload all controls using set_value, which does work for the first drop down (the countries) just fine, however the second drop down stays empty( as there was no ".change" triggered on the "country_id" to populate "state_id".

Similarly I am asked to re-attach the file

So what I need and is not working is after form_validation fail to

1. Load up second drop down with data => RESOLVED see below with .trigger event
2. Select the previous selection int he second drop down => ALMOST RESOLVED however only if I use alert :)
3. The attachment should still stay attached until form is dismissed or committed successfully => NOT RESOLVED

I feel like I need to manually trigger the data change to get (1) but in my case I have a foreach (see above) where I just add lines and if the selection is the same I simply set is as "selected" but nothing happens after.

Here is the AJAX part

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#country_id").change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>location/getCountries",
                        data: {country_id: $(this).val()},
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#state_id").html(data);
                            $("#state_id").val(null);    
                        }
                    });
                });

                <?php if (!empty(set_value('country_id'))) : ?>
                var value = "<?php echo set_value('country_id'); ?>";
                $('#country_id').val(value);
                $('#country_id').trigger('change');                    

                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (!empty(set_value('state_id'))) : ?>
                var value = "<?php echo set_value('state_id'); ?>";
                //without this alert the selection doesn't work
                alert(value);
                $('#state_id').val(value);
                $('#state_id').trigger('change');
                <?php endif; ?>
            });

        </script>
```

So I am getting the values saved only if I use an alert. This seems to be an asynchronous execution where the selection of second drop down is done before it gets populated, so the last thing to do is to figure out how to wait.

Still to do the attachment part

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For select, you can store selected state value in local storage and after redirect, check whether the value exists in local storage then set selected state by jquery. For this purpose, you need to call ajax on document ready to get selected country's states.
But you should use the ajax to submit the form so that the inputs will remain selected.

Comment: @Marius can you share your code like ajax and others

Comment: I added the ajax part, too, in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this code at the end of view page**

> For country dropdown

```
<?php if (!empty(set_value('country_id'))) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = "<?php echo set_value('country_id'); ?>";

        $('select[name="country_id"]').find('option[value="'+value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> For state dropdown

```
<?php if (!empty(set_value('state_id'))) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = "<?php echo set_value('state_id'); ?>";

        $('select[name="state_id"]').find('option[value="'+value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: your answer pointed me to the right direction so I am getting really close. One thing I also needed was the .trigger event (see my edited question) which fixed the population of second drop down. Now the issue is a rush condition as it tries to select the value before the second drop down gets the values. To prove that I used an alert statement between the second drop down fill and second drop down selection and it does works. So the last thing to do is to figure out how to wait for the population of data to occur (since it comes from DB) before selecting the value in second drop down

Comment: Add set timeout funtion  in second dropdown
For example :
setTimeout(function(){
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = "<?php echo set_value('state_id'); ?>";

        $('select[name="state_id"]').find('option[value="'+value+'"]').attr("selected",true);
    </script>
    }, 1000);

Comment: It worked with the timeout, the only concern I have is if the system needs more than 1 second to load up. I know I can increase the interval, but ideally my function will execute right after the first one is completed. Thanks Mani!

Comment: You don't need to extend the time because $(document).ready(function() { }) is once the page is loading completed the function will call...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below points

1) For `select` tag, use `set_select()`, like this

```
<select name="myselect">
    <option value="one" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'one', TRUE); ?> >One</option>
    <option value="two" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'two'); ?> >Two</option>
    <option value="three" <?php echo  set_select('myselect', 'three'); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

2) If the form validation failed, call your ajax function to set second drop down.

3) For attachment,  Whatever result of the form validation, first upload the image and keep the image path in session variable. After successful form validation, save the data into database and destroy the session variable.

Comment: For the drop downs I am really close, I think with a bit of a push to figure out the rush condition (see my comments) it will be resolved. For the attachment I think it is a good idea, not sure if code igniter offers something built in or best practices for this scenario. But without any other idea I will start to implement your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

edited >>>

```
**html**
<?php 
if (isset($edit) && !empty($edit)) {  //while editing 
     $StateID = $edit['StateID'];
     $CountryID = $edit['CountryID'];
} else {                             // while adding
     $StateID = set_value('StateID');
     $CountryID = set_value('CountryID');
   } ?>
 <div class="col-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="mb-0">Country</label>
                <select class="form-control Country" id="country" name="CountryID" data_state_value="<?php echo $StateID; ?>" >
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($country as $row) {
                        $selected = ($row->id == $CountryID) ? 'selected' : '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $row->id . '"' . $selected . '>' . $row->country_name . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <span class="text-danger font9"><?php echo form_error('CountryID'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="mb-0">State</label>
                <select class="form-control State" id="State" name="StateID">
                </select>
                <span class="text-danger font9"><?php echo form_error('StateID'); ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>

**script**
```

```
 $(document).on('change', '.Country', function () {
    var country_id = $(this).val();
    var state_id = $(this).attr('data_state_value');
    url = $("body").attr('b_url');
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "Education/fetch_state",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            country_id: country_id,
            state_id: state_id
        },
        success: function (res) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(res);
            $('#State').html('<option value="">Select State</option>' + response.view);
            $('.State').trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
$('.Country').trigger('change');
```

```
**controller** 
public function fetch_state() {
    $data = array();
    if (isset($_POST['country_id']) && !empty($_POST['country_id'])) {
        $states = $this->Location_model->fetch_state($this->input->post('country_id')); // array of states 
        $view = array();
        if (!empty($states)) {
            foreach ($states as $val) {
                $selected = (isset($_POST['state_id']) && !empty($_POST['state_id']) && $_POST['state_id'] == $val['id']) ? 'selected' : '';
                $view[] = "<option value='" . $val['id'] . "'" . $selected . ">" . $val['states_name'] . "</option>";
            }
            $data['view'] = $view;
            $data['status'] = 0;
        } else {
            $data['status'] = 0;
            $data['view'] = '<option value="">No State Found</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $data['status'] = 0;
        $data['view'] = '<option value="">Select State</option>';
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: @Marius Please Check the answer